# Alt title images in category page

Tags: magento2

In the category page I would like to show its corresponding alt for each product image, but by default my theme Claue show the product name in the alt label.

In the phtml file /design/frontend/Mgs/claue/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml

stripTags($_product->getImageLabel(), null, true); ?>

The problem is that for some images  it shows the alternative text and for others it does not and show the alt="".

Somebody could help me?

Answer (score 0):

Its using the image label and not the product name. Change your snippet to :

```
stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true);
```

Comment: Yes, I want to use the label name and not the product name. 
The problem is that although the product has a label name on the category page, some product is not shown while on the product page if it is displayed correctly.
From my point of view it does not make sense for the same image to have different alts one on the category page and another on the products page and for this reason I want to show the alt of the image always and not the name of the product.